# Rails check if the value corresponding to a hash key is an empty array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

A function in a rails 3 app returns the following hash

```
{:"white-wines"=>[]}
```

which I want to treat as a false result (meaning that if the hash value is an empty array I want to skip it).
How can I achieve the above?

Comment: What do you mean by "hash value"? Does the hash always have only one key?

Comment: No, it could return an array of values, but when no results are found it returns the above.

Comment: Your accepted answer and question don't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array#empty?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-empty-3F) and [`Hash#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) are the methods you need to look into.

```
h = {:"white-wines"=>[]}
puts "empty" if h[:"white-wines"].empty?
#= > empty
```